# Inject timely metadata for avplayeritem ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, avasset, avplayeritem

Hi i have a requirement in my project. I am playing live streaming content in avplayer but here along with stream i am not getting metadata. That meta data i am getting from another api. How can i inject timely metadata in avplayeritem. I had go through the apple developer site and came to know that id3taggenerator and mediafilesegmenter for achive this in terminal.But after release app to appstore we cannot generate id3tags in app right ? So i want to know is there any way to do this in ios project programatically.Please help me here i stuck.

Comment: Did you find the solution for this?

Comment: No i did not get.